# How to change color of navbar-inverse (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, background-color

I've got a simple question which is giving me a hard time. I am creating a navbar using Bootstrap and i am trying to change its color but I can't.

**jsp**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
```

**css**

```
navbar-inverse {
background-color:whatever;
     }
```

Am I doing anything wrong in css?

Comment: If your example is accurate then you you meed to add a **.** (dot) to specify a class. **.navbar-inverse** and make sure your stylesheet is placed after bootstraps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is what the default for `navbar-inverse` is:

```
.navbar-inverse {
     background-color: #222;
     border-color: #080808;
}
```

Which of course is dark, not the color you want.

So instead of using an `!important` on your custom rule, you COULD go search for this rule in the bootstrap css.

Barring that, place an `!important` on your custom rule and it should override.

Answer (score 2):

navbar-inverse is a class so, you can call it by adding ' . ' before the name of the class

```
.navnavbar-inverse {
    background-color:whatever !important;
}
```

an !important on your custom rule override any other rule of your custom CSS, and now everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I always avoid the use of `!important` as it can create problems in later part of your project. Assign an id to your element and style it. So, I normally go with the below mentioned way---

```css
#nav_bar {
background-color: red;
border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
           
           </head>
           <body>
           <nav id="nav_bar" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation"></nav>

           </body>
           </html>
```

Hope this helps!